# Caching issue for JS/CSS in Media Library node

Tags: media-library, caching, javascript

We have one caching issues on live site. Actually we keep JS/CSS files in sitecore media library so after every  prod deployment when we publish updates JS file we have to press Ctrl+F5 to load latest JS file updates. This is fine for Developers but not for visitors and we can't instruct every visitors to press Ctrl+F5.

```
<script src="/-/media/common/js/productlisting.js"></script>
```

To mitigate this issue we are planning to add time-stamp as a query string in **src** attribute in `<script>` element as described in below URL

https://css-tricks.com/can-we-prevent-css-caching/

and this looks like need modification in sitecore media pipelines. Any idea how can we do this.

OR

Any other suggestion much appreciated

Thanks

**UPDATE 07/17/2017**

Below Patch works for me

```
<mediaProvider>
        <patch:attribute name="type">MyProject.Pipelines.CacheBustingMediaProvider, MyProject</patch:attribute>
</mediaProvider>
```

I see very strange behavior see screenshot. While debugging I found code between line no. 16 and 34 is not getting executed. You can see when I tried to set debug at line no. 14 it throw exception. finally debug point come to line no. 12 and then directly goes to line no. 36 and goes out. Any idea on this.

[image]

Comment: You need to override the default MediaManager. We already have an example of how this is done (including cache busting) here: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/4682/medialinkserverurl-per-site/4683#4683

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to continue storing these files in the media library (there are pros and cons to this approach), you'll need to subclass `Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaProvider`, override `GetMediaUrl(MediaItem item, MediaUrlOptions options)`, and patch it into your configuration.

The default Media Provider is set in Sitecore.config with `<mediaProvider type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" />`. You'll want to use a config file to patch this value to your custom MediaProvider class.

In `GetMediaUrl()`, you have access to the MediaItem object, you have access to the `Extension` field which you could use to determine if the item is JS/CSS. You'll also need to pull the updated date from the statistics of the Sitecore item.

Finally, you'll want to get the URL that the default MediaProvider returns, and modify that. The following is the basic jist of what I'm suggesting.

```
public class CacheBustingMediaProvider : Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaProvider {
    public override string GetMediaUrl(MediaItem item, MediaUrlOptions options)
    {
        var requiredExtensions = new[] {"js", "css"};

        var baseURL = base.GetMediaUrl(item, options);

        if (requiredExtensions.Contains(item.Extension))
        {
            var rawItem = item.Database.GetItem(item.ID);
            var itemTimestamp = (rawItem.Statistics.Updated.Ticks - 621355968000000000) / 10000000;
            var urlComponents = baseURL.Split('?');

            Sitecore.Collections.SafeDictionary<string> queryString;

            if (urlComponents.Length > 1)
            {
                queryString = Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.ParseQueryString(urlComponents[1]);
            }
            else
            {
                queryString = new Sitecore.Collections.SafeDictionary<string>();
            }

            queryString["t"] = itemTimestamp.ToString();

            var finalQueryString = Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.BuildQueryString(queryString, true);

            return urlComponents[0] + "?" + finalQueryString;
        }

        return baseURL;
    }
}
```

There's another few examples of using a MediaProvider here: https://allthingssitecore.com/2014/03/26/integrating-a-cdn-into-your-sitecore-solution/

Comment: Except; don't use timestamp. Use the revision field; it's a guid that is generated whenever the item updates.

Comment: @MarkCassidy I could see it both ways. I personally think it would be better to use the timestamp to make it easier to debug, since you could easily determine what version you're getting.

Comment: Sure I will try this. Does below patch will work
<sitecore>
    <mediaLibrary>
      <mediaProvider type="Myporject.Pipelines.CacheBustingMediaProvider, Myporject"
                     patch:after="Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaProvider, Sitecore.Kernel">
      </mediaProvider>
    </mediaLibrary>
  </sitecore>

Comment: @Sukhi I believe you want patch:instead, not patch:after

Comment: Can you please check my update in Post

Comment: @Sukhi Not sure about the breakpoint binding issue, but can you check the extension field under the Information section on the item in the media library and make sure it's js/css?

Comment: yeah I checked..Extension is js for JS file , Mime Type is application/x-javascript

Comment: FYI I put this line on MainLayout.cshtml which render JS from media library
<script src="/~/media/JS/samplejsfile.js"></script>

Comment: Ah, well you'll need to generate the link to the media item through Sitecore to make use of the MediaProvider. Probably a cleaner way to do this, but something like this will get the URL. If you need more help, lets move to chat @{ var rawItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/sitecore/media library/js/samplejsfile"); var mediaItem = new Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem(rawItem); var jsURL = Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(mediaItem); }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62374/discussion-between-sukhi-and-matthew-fitzgerald-chamberlain).

Comment: Awesome below code worked out for me

@{ 
var rawItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/sitecore/media library/js/samplejsfile"); 
var mediaItem = new Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem(rawItem); 
string jsURL = Sitecore.StringUtil.EnsurePrefix('/', Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(mediaItem)); 
}
<script src="@jsURL"></script>

Output of this code is 
<script src="/-/media/JS/samplejsfile.ashx?t=1500354198"></script>
which is expected where we can see time-stamp added

thanks a lot for your help on this

Comment: Great Sukhi. If this fixed your issue, it would be great if you could mark my answer as accepted :)